# How to reduce each column of a dataset?

Tags: dataset

Given a simple dataset like this one:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

...I want to apply some reduction function (like `Total` or `MinMax`) to each column separately, so that the result would be a *one-row* dataset, with the same number and names of columns as in the original dataset.

For example, if the reduction function were `Total`, the desired result would be

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For `MinMax` it would be

[image: Mathematica graphics]

&c.

---

Does the built-in `Dataset` functionality directly support this type of operation?  Or does one have to unpack the `Dataset`, apply the reductions to the columns in the underlying data, and stuff the results in a new `Dataset`?

**NB:** If the former is the case, I'm looking for more than an incantation here.  I want also to understand how the proposed solution follows from the `Dataset` syntax given in the documentation.

---

FWIW, the code I used to create the `data` dataset is given below.

```
data = Module[
  {
      numberOfRows = 8
   , columnNames = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"}
   , makeColumn
  }

  , SeedRandom[0]
  ; makeColumn[] := RandomReal[{0, 1}, numberOfRows]
  ; Dataset[Transpose[Association[# -> makeColumn[] & /@ columnNames], AllowedHeads -> All]]
]
```

Comment: Have you tried `data[All,Total]` ?

Comment: @alancalvitti: Yes.  It doesn't do the job.

Comment: Forgot `Transpose` - posted as answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `Total`, this suffices:

`data[Total /* List]`

but for a general approach that also works with `MinMax`, try:

`data[Transpose][List, Total]`

and

`data[Transpose][List, MinMax]`

Comment: Thanks.  For `Total`, the results for both your incantations match the desired result given in the question, but the result for the `MinMax` one doesn't.  (I'm using v. 10.4.0.0.)

Comment: @kjo, the issue with `MinMax` is a limitation of `Dataset` formatting. Try `Normal` to look at the underlying `Association`.

Comment: Thanks.  After I wrote my comment I figured something related to formatting was afoot.  I posted a [question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/115246/2464) about it.

Answer (score 5):

You may use `Merge`.

```
datMinMax = data[Merge[MinMax]];
datMinMax["A"]
(* {0.238452, 0.976188} *)

datTotal = data[Merge[Total]];
datTotal["B"]
(* 4.32817 *)
```

Hope this helps.