# How to make datasets display correctly?

Tags: dataset, display

**NB:** The problem illustrated below is truly ubiquitous.  I hope the examples given below are sufficiently different to demonstrate this fact, and to discourage answers that hinge on the details of the examples.

---

**Example 1:**

```
columnSpecs = Module[
   {
      numberOfRows = 4
    , columnNames = {"a", "b", "c"}
    , numberOfColumns
    , columns
   }

   , numberOfColumns = Length[columnNames]
   ; SeedRandom[0]
   ; columns = Partition[ RandomSample[ Range[numberOfRows * numberOfColumns]], numberOfRows]
   ; AssociationThread[columnNames, columns]
];   


ugly = Dataset[columnSpecs][Transpose];
nice = Dataset[ Transpose[columnSpecs, AllowedHeads -> All]];
```

Now, the datasets `ugly` and `nice` have exactly the same content:

```
Normal[ugly] == Normal[nice]
(* True *)
```

but they "look" different:

```
{ugly, nice}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(**ugly:** "What does `nice` have that I don't?"  Life is so unfair.)

---

**Example 2:**

In this case, the RHS expressions in the definitions of `ugly` and `nice` have exactly the same form, but differ in content.

```
ugly = Dataset[{<|"a" -> 11, "b" ->  2 , "c" -> 12|>}];
nice = Dataset[{<|"a" -> 11, "b" -> "2", "c" -> 12|>}];

{ugly, nice}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Bottom line: `Datasets` get displayed inconsistently.

---

### How can one canonicalize "ugly" `Dataset`s so that they look "nice"?

As pointed out at the beginning of this post, in my experience, "ugly" `Dataset`s arise in a very wide variety of ways, and therefore it would be a fool's errand to attempt to solve this problem at the point of generation of these "ugly" `Dataset`s (there would be too many do's and don't's to remember).  For instance, one could avoid the "ugly" `Dataset` of Example 1 by using `Dataset[columnSpecs][Transpose[#, AllowedHeads->All]&]` instead of `Dataset[columnSpecs][Transpose]`, but this solution is very specific to the particularities of `Transpose`, and is therefore useless for the case shown in Example 2.

Hence, I'm much more interested in ways to canonicalize (i.e. *fix*) the "ugly" `Dataset`s after-the-fact (the "remedial" strategy) than in ways to avoid them in the first place (the "preventive" strategy).  One can hope the remedial strategy would be the one more likely to yield the more generally applicable solution.

Comment: It's a `TypeSystem` thing. Compare `FullForm@nice` with `FullForm@ugly` and check [this excellent Q&A](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/89080/visualizing-type-system-operations).

Comment: Also relevant: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/87479/18476

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The reason for the difference between `ugly` and `nice` is in the (hidden) data type that `Dataset` assigns them:

```
ugly = Dataset[{<|"a" -> 11, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 12|>}];
nice = Dataset[{<|"a" -> 11, "b" -> "2", "c" -> 12|>}];
<< Dataset`;
<< TypeSystem`;

In[43]:= ugly // GetType

(* Vector[Assoc[Atom[Enumeration["a", "b", "c"]], Atom[Integer], 3], 1] *)

In[44]:= nice // GetType

(* Vector[Struct[{"a", "b", "c"}, {Atom[Integer], Atom[String], Atom[Integer]}], 1] *)
```

`Dataset` bases its typesetting on these types. In this case, there isn't a good typesetting rule implemented for the `Vector[Assoc[Atom[Enumeration[...],...]]]` type (this is a bug that'll be fixed in a future version of *Mathematica*).

In order to bypass this, we can assign `ugly` a type manually, via `Dataset`'s hidden second argument, so:

```
notugly = Dataset[{<|"a" -> 11, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 12|>}, 
          Vector[Struct[{"a", "b", "c"}, {Atom[Integer], Atom[Integer], Atom[Integer]}], 1]]
```

This is possible because the same underlying data can conform to several different types, one of which could have a nice typesetting rule, as `notugly` does:

[image: non-ugly typesetting]

Comment: The display situation is still rather a mess.  It seems Mma is not exploiting structure it is aware of.  To illustrate in 12.1, Dataset@GroupBy[
  Range[6], {If[PrimeQ@#, "yes", "no"] &, 
   If[EvenQ@#, "even", "odd"] &}]` displays hierchically, but transposing it gives a nice 2-way display, as does transposing that last result.